# Why is my dict overwriting the list when I have more than one item Python

Tags: python

my problem is that I want to get data (JSON) from a database and put it into a new JSON structure to UPDATE a table. Like parsing. Now I have this code:

```
for x in range(len(data_set)):
    data = json.loads(data_set[x][1])
    items = []
    item = {}

    try:
        for weapon in data['weapons']:
            item['type'] = 'item_weapon'
            item['name'] = weapon['name'] # overwrites items[]
            item['count'] = weapon['ammo']
            items.append(item)
            #item.clear() # also overwrites items ????
            print(items)
            # print(weapon['label'])
    except Exception:
        #print("No weapons found")
        pass
```

I can navigate thru my data and everything works. Until I have 2 or more items to append, which means that the inner for-loop is running >1 times. Then the new item is overwriting the whole items[] list before it uses `items.append(item)`. At the end I get the exact amount of item ind items. But its overwritten with the last item.
Output is:

```
        {
            "count": 51242,
            "name": "black_money",
            "type": "item_account"
        },
        {
            "count": 51242,
            "name": "black_money",
            "type": "item_account"
        },
        ...
```

but this should be two different items. But at `item['name'] = weapon['name'] # overwrites items[]` all "old" items are overwritten.

Comment: Move `item = {}` to inside the inner for-loop. You need to create a new item dict each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `item` is defined outside the loop. What you are doing inside the loop is get a *reference* ("pointer" of sorts) to the same dict `item`, modifying its details, and appending the same reference of `item` to the list. Meaning, your list contains multiple references to the exact same object.

To fix this: define `item` inside the loop instead, so that a new `item` object is created at each iteration.

```
for x in range(len(data_set)):
    data = json.loads(data_set[x][1])
    items = []

    try:
        for weapon in data['weapons']:
            item = {}
            item['type'] = 'item_weapon'
            item['name'] = weapon['name'] # overwrites items[]
            item['count'] = weapon['ammo']
            items.append(item)
            #item.clear() # also overwrites items ????
            print(items)
            # print(weapon['label'])
    except Exception:
        #print("No weapons found")
        pass
```